# Why do bmp files plot in wrong spot in QField?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qfield

I'm relatively new to QField and have successfully packaged a project to QField.  However when I opened it, most layers have displayed correctly except for some bmp layers - these have plotted in the completely wrong spot despite having the same CRS as the project.  What could be causing this?  They display just fine in my desktop project.